# How to round all columns Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My code:

```
>>> mean = all_data.groupby(['Id'])[features].agg('mean').reset_index()
>>> print(mean)

0          0.000000
1        362.000000
2          0.000000
3          0.000000
4         60.093750
5          0.000000
```

I want to round this numbers to two decimal places like:

```
0          0.00
1        362.00
2          0.00
3          0.00
4         60.09
5          0.00
```

Answer (score 5):

on recent pandas versions, you can just `df.round(2)`

Comment: I tried that, not working. Output is same

Comment: you need to assign the result not just run it i.e. df=df.round(2)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz This is giving unpredictable results for me. Some entries it works for, but not all of them...

Comment: use numpy.round , as , df = np.round(df ,2)